# Visual elements selector (picker) in iframe

Tags: selenium, jquery-plugins, html-parsing

I'm developing a kind of interactive parsing tool, where users should be able to load any external web page by entering URL and visually pick elements.

Loaded page should have all it's original UI.

Experience of picking should be like in web inspector of a browser.

---

I think, they are two ways:

**1. Iframe and picker**

Load a web page to `<iframe>`, then, using some picking plugin, let user to pick any element.

Are libraries available, that allows to visually pick element in `<iframe>`?

**2. Browser plugin, that will provide picking UI**

I think, it's better from user experience, because full page is available in it's original state.

But, supporting plugin for many browsers with many versions can quickly become hard.

---

Also, some websites are build with javascript (React…), and I should have an interpreter, that will bootstrap DOM in headless mode.

---

Which ways can You, guys, advise?

What stack of plugins, libraries, packages to use?

Comment: Either proxy all the resources or just push the grabbed content will work that will not be a problem. @AntonAL how is the progress of your project. if you had a working copy, we can make a conversation about it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Option one won’t work due to cross domain security restrictions. You would have to proxy the remote sites via you server to overcome this.